# IF statement to end the game

Tags: flash

So basically I have a button which moves to a random location on the screen based off a timer.

What if statement would be correct to end the game if the person doesn't click the button before it moves to the new location?

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

stop();

var timmyTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000)
var score:int = 0;


timmyTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick)
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;                         

timmyTimer.start();

function tick(t:TimerEvent):void {
if(t.target.delay > 500){ 
t.target.delay -= 100; }
addChild(mcBall);
mcBall.x = Math.floor(Math.random() *(stage.stageWidth - mcBall.width));
mcBall.y = Math.floor(Math.random() *(stage.stageHeight - mcBall.height));
mcBall.nextFrame();
}

stop();

mcBall.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler);

function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void {
timmyTimer.reset();
score +=1;
updateScores();
mcBall.x = Math.floor(Math.random() *(stage.stageWidth - mcBall.width));
mcBall.y = Math.floor(Math.random() *(stage.stageHeight - mcBall.height));
mcBall.nextFrame();
removeChild(mcBall);
}

function updateScores():void {
lblScore.text = String(score);
}

function endGame():void {
timmyTimer.stop();
gotoAndStop(3);
mcBall.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler);
removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick);
removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler);
                            removeChild(mcBall);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If user clicks the button before firing timer complete event, reset the timer and move the button to new position.
If timer complete event fires, end the game.

```
var totalPoint: int = 0;

// timer for 5 seconds
var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000,1);

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,function (e:TimerEvent):void{

    // End the game.

    // Change the button disable.
    button.enable = false;
});


function buttonClicked(e: MouseEvent):void{

    // If user click before 5seconds, point up and restart the timer.
    totalPoint++;

    // Reset timer here.
    timer.stop();
    timer.reset();

    buttonMove();
}

function buttonMove():void{

    // Set button new position here.

    // Start timer.
    timer.start();
}
```